# Issue with euclidean division in Python

Tags: python

First of all, sorry if this has been already answered, I have been searching for a while and did not find anything.

In short, I'm trying to create a programe to automate some tasks I have. In one, I have a loop on days, between a start date and an end date. For each iteration, I'm trying to get the lag in months between the current date and the start date. So I tried to use the euclidean division, which seemed appropriate.
Bottom line is, it works for almost all dates except a few, for instance:

```
import datetime as dt
start=dt.date(2022, 7, 1)
end=dt.date(2023, 7, 1)
average_days=365/12

lag1=(end-start).days/average_days
lag2=(end-start).days//average_days
```

For these dates in particular, lag1 gives me 12 while lag2 gives me 11. Where does this difference come from exactly, and how can I work around this issue to continue using the euclidean division ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "euclidean division"?

Comment: I mean getting the quotient of the division, which is what I do in the definition of lag2

Comment: It's a bit weird, but I think the problem comes from float precision. If you look at the rest `365%average_days` it gives `30.416666666666654`, which is slightly lower than `average_days` at `30.416666666666668`

Comment: For reference, Python refers to this operation as ["floor division"](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-floor-division).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered here:

[Dividing a Number by a Decimal Using the Integer Division Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062645/dividing-a-number-by-a-decimal-using-the-integer-division-operator)

In short, 365/12 is a float and is not exact after a certain number of digits. And could be a tiny bit larger than what you would expect. So when you divide 365 by this number it will be 11.99999... And `//` is floor division which truncates the decimals, resulting in 11.

Comment: To correct this problem, I have a solution but it's a bit hacky (and there might be better ways): test if `np.isclose(365%average_days, average_days)`, and when it is, add 1 to lag2

Comment: Best practice in general would be to flag/vote to close a question as a duplicate.